# footrule in exam package

Tags: exam

How to change the footer rule using \footrule to be thicker, boxed etc in exam package. The command \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt} generates error unknown command \footrulewidth.
Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In the title of the question you mention the `exam` documentclass, in the tags you added `beamer`, which is an entirely different documentclass. Pleas clarify that. Please also prepare a short [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far. Please also clarify the meaning of "thicker, boxed etc".

Comment: The foot rule is draw by `\@fullfoot` using `\hrule`.  Use `\patchcmd` (etoolbox package) to replace `\hrule` with `\hrule height2pt`.